# Filter out combination of fields in HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, having

I know this might be pretty basic but I thought it'll be much quicker here.

```
    +----------+----------+---------+
    | PersonID | No Shows | Cancels |
    +----------+----------+---------+
    |        1 |        2 |       0 |
    |        1 |        5 |       1 |
    |        1 |        0 |       0 |
    |        2 |        0 |       0 |
    |        2 |        0 |       0 |
    |        3 |        1 |       0 |
    |        3 |        0 |       0 |
    |        4 |        1 |       1 |
    |        4 |        3 |       2 |
    |        4 |        0 |       0 |
    +----------+----------+---------+
```

I'm trying to eliminate people which have combination of both Total of NoShows and Cancels as 0. Eg: `PersonID=2`

Attempt:

```
SELECT
    PersonID
    ,SUM(NoShows) AS TotalNS
    ,SUM(Cancels) AS TotalCanc

FROM Table1
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING SUM(NoShows) > 0 AND SUM(Cancels) > 0
```

This obviously won't work since it'll start removing persons if either of NoShows or Cancels is 0. Eg: `PersonID=3`

Desired Output:

```
+--------------+----------+---------+
|     PersonID | No Shows | Cancels |
+--------------+----------+---------+
|            1 |        7 |       1 |
|            3 |        1 |       0 |
|            4 |        4 |       3 |
+--------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: OR instead of AND?

Comment: @ZLK I think I've had a long day at work.

Comment: @G.Arima Person 3 would get removed since their cancels=0. But I want them since NoShows !=0

Comment: yes i figured that, that's why posted the correct answer within seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out and let me know in case you face any difficulties.

```
SELECT
    PersonID
    ,SUM(NoShows) AS TotalNS
    ,SUM(Cancels) AS TotalCanc

FROM Table1
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING SUM(NoShows) > 0 or SUM(Cancels) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:

> I'm trying to obtain only those which have combination of both Total
>   of NoShows and Cancels as 0. Eg: PersonID=2

The answer is:

```
SELECT PersonID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING SUM(NoShows) = 0 AND SUM(Cancels) = 0;
```

It is unclear to me why you would accept an answer with different logic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Gordon. I've edited the question so that it makes sense now. My bad.